# How to pass an input as an argument in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that gets an input with the `read` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

read id
```

I can run the script `$./my_script.sh` and after that it wants me to enter the input (id). How can I enter the id as an argument to the script? I mean something like this:

```
$./my_script.sh id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert something like this in your script:

```
id=$1
```

`$1` equals to the first command line argument passed to the script, `$2` to the second one, etc.

Of course it would be wise to check first if the command line argument was provided at all. You can use something like this:

```
if [ -n "$1" ]; then
  id=$1
else
  read id
fi
```

The command (yes, it is a command) `[` checks for a condition (an equivalent command is `test`). If the first argument is non-empty (`-n`), then the command `id=$1` is executed; otherwise, `read id` is executed.